# Adding array elements inside of a loop

Tags: java, arrays

```
    //different types of items purchased
    System.out.print("How many different types of items are being purchased? " );
    ArraySize = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    //arrays - being defined after ArraySize
    String[] item = new String[ArraySize];              //each item             
    int[] itemsPurchased = new int[ArraySize];          //item purchased
    double[] price = new double[ArraySize];             //price for each 'line' on the receipt
    double[] itemPrice = new double[ArraySize];         //price of item purchased

    for (int i=0; i<ArraySize; i++){                    //i = variable element counter

    //name of item purchased
    System.out.print("Item purchased: ");
    item[i] = input.nextLine();

    //number of items purchased
    System.out.print("Quantity: ");
    itemsPurchased[i] = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();


    //determines price of item based on what was purchased
    if (item.equals("Shoes") || item.equals("shoes") || item.equals("SHOES"))
        itemPrice[i] = 50.00;

    if (item.equals("T-Shirt") || item.equals("t-shirt") || (item.equals("T-SHIRT")))
        itemPrice[i] = 40.00;

    if (item.equals("Shorts") || item.equals("shorts") || item.equals("SHORTS"))
        itemPrice[i] = 75.00;

    if (item.equals("Cap") || item.equals("cap") || item.equals("CAP"))
        itemPrice[i] = 20.00;

    if (item.equals("Jacket") || item.equals("jacket") || item.equals("JACKET"))
        itemPrice[i] = 100.00;

    //adds item and item amount
        price[i] += (itemsPurchased[i] * itemPrice[i]);

    }//end for
```

I'm trying to make a receipt lines that look something like

Item ---------- Quantity -----------Cost

Item ---------- Quantity -----------Cost

Item ---------- Quantity -----------Cost

but the line I sat up to hold cost (very last line I linked) isn't holding anything after the first element. 
I only linked what I thought was relevant, I can give the rest of the code if needed.

Comment: You can use `item.equalsIgnoreCase("AnYKIndOfStRiNg)"`to not use those  3 equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (item.equals("Shoes") || item.equals("shoes") || item.equals("SHOES"))
```

`item` has the type of `String[]`, it will never be equal to a `String`. You are testing if a an array of strings is equal to an individual string. This will never return true. You most likely want to be using `item[i]` instead of just `item`.

Because of the error above, a value is never assigned to `itemPrice[i]`. And in turn `price[i]` will always be 0.

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain again? I've just start using arrays so I'm not entirely sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All your lines that have:
    if (item.equals("Shoes") || item.equals("shoes") || item.equals("SHOES"))

should use item[i]

so for example:

if (item[i].equalsIgnoreCase("shoes"))